# How to change the language of Minimize/Maximize button in a PartStack?

Tags: eclipse, rcp, e4

I am a RCP E4 developer. And I need to internationalize my app. In fact, I have finished most of the work. But I can't find a way to change the language of Minimize/Maximize button in a PartStack. I have googled a lot but find nothing useful. Anyone can help me?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The minimize/maximize buttons are from the `CTabFolder` control.

The tool tip text for these comes from the `SWTMessages.properties` file in the `org.eclipse.swt.internal` package which is in the platform specific SWT plugin.

It looks like the [Eclipse Babel](https://eclipse.org/babel/) project already has translations of the SWT messages.

Comment: So I need to add Babel to my project? how to do that, I have tried before,but failed.

Comment: As I understand it you just download the appropriate language packs from their site and add the appropriate fragment plugins to your target platform (but I have not used this myself).

Comment: I have visited the  Eclipse Babel site. My application need to support French.But in the website, there are so many files associated with French(see here:http://download.eclipse.org/technology/babel/babel_language_packs/R0.14.1/neon/neon.php#fr). Which one should I download? Thank you so much.

Comment: I imagine it is the one with '-eclipse-' in the name.

Comment: I downloaded the "BabelLanguagePack-eclipse-fr_4.6.0.v20161126060001.zip" and extract it. There are two folders(features and plugins).In the "features" folders, there are some .html files ,feature.xml and feature.properties.In the "plugins"  folders, there are plenty of jar files.So what should I do?

Comment: Hi! I have added the feature to my project.The good news is that the language of Minimize/Maximize button has changed into French. However, when I change language of the application, it's still French without any change.Besides, when I export the project, some errors occur (Error:Processing inclusion from feature org.eclipse.pde.container.feature: Bundle org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state.nl_fr_4.6.0.v20161126060001 failed to resolve.:
 Host plug-in org.eclipse.osgi.compatibility.state_0.0.0 has not been found.
)